# iPad custom/dynamic layout

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am a newbie to iOS development. I have gone through a couple of tutorials and know the basics, but currently I am stuck on how to proceed further. I am planning to create an app for basic home automation (i.e. switching lights, measuring temperature etc.). The backend is all set, so this is just about the frontend. This is what I am planning to do:

- The main view of the app should display a floor plan or the layout of the house
- On this floor plan you should be able to add lights/sensors/etc. - lets say objects to keep it generic
- These objects should be draggable so that you can arrange them on the floor plan according to where they really are (physically) - ideally this drag mode is toggable similar to rearranging icons on the home screen
- Each object should have a popover view (i.e. to set the dimmer intensity, switch lights etc.)

I know there is a lot of work to do, but I don't really know how to set this up. Current alternatives:

1. Create a custom UIView subclass that contains all the logic an do the drawing in custom code, i.e. the dragging, the popover positioning etc. - but I have the feeling that I wouldn't really be leveraging the iOS framework capabilities
2. Display the floor plan as an UIImageView and one UIButton for each object. This has the advantage that I can use StoryBoard to do the layouting and wiring (i.e. create segues for popovers etc.) - but I simply can't figure out how to do this with a variable number of buttons (since I don't know in advance how many buttons there will be). Is there some way to create these buttons in code?
3. Use a custom UITableView. I have seen a couple of examples where they seem to use table views even if the layout has nothing to do with tables (like in my example) but I haven't found any tutorials that explain this concept in more detail

Or am I totally on the wrong track? Any input is appreciated.

Thanks
D.

UPDATE:
After some more research and thought on this I think the way to go with iOS 6 is to use an UICollectionView with a custom layout. Once I have come up with a complete solution I will post it here. For older iOS versions I think it would be promising to go with Option Nr. 2 - i.e. creating each UIButton (for the automation objects e.g. lights) in code and having a custom UIView subclass to do the layouting of these buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I think UICollectionView is ideal for this usage scenario and I am just lucky to have started with iOS programming just as it was introduced to the framework. The following example is a UICollectionView that displays its elements according to their inherent coordinates. This example could also be applied to positioning objects on a map. I couldn't find any examples elsewhere so I'll post the main steps here (since I am a beginner please correct any mistakes).

To start off I created a simple project with one view and storyboard in XCode. I removed the standard view and inserted a Collection View Controller instead and configured my UICollectionViewController subclass as the class that should be used (in the properties of the controller in storyboard).

For the demo just set the background of the default UICollectionViewCell to a color and set the Identifier to "AutomationCell" for this example (if you change it be sure to adjust the code below).

First I create a simple object with some properties that represents an object that should be displayed on the floor plan:

```
@interface AULYAutomationObject : NSObject

@property NSString *title;
@property CGPoint position;

@end
```

Then I need my own delegate as subclass to the standard UICollectionViewDelegate since  my custom UICollectionViewLayout will not have direct access to the dataSource objects. Therefore I provide a method that will give me the position of the object:

```
@protocol AULYAutomationObjectLayoutDelegate <UICollectionViewDelegate>

- (CGPoint)getPositionForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

Make sure to implement this protocol in your controller like this:

```
@interface AULYViewController : UICollectionViewController <AULYAutomationObjectLayoutDelegate>
```

Then I implemented the standard datasource and delegate methods along with my custom one in the view controller subclass:

```
@interface AULYViewController ()

@property NSArray *objects;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end

@implementation AULYViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up the data source
    NSMutableArray *automationObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

    // add some objects here...

    self.objects = [automationObjects copy];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewController 
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.objects.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AULYAutomationObjectViewCell *cell = [collectionView     dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AutomationCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // If you have a custom UICollectionViewCell with a label as outlet 
    // you could for example then do this:
    // AULYAutomationObject *automationObject = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    // cell.label.text = automationObject.title;
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - AULYAutomationObjectLayoutDelegate

- (CGPoint)getPositionForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AULYAutomationObject *automationObject = self.objects[indexPath.item];
    return automationObject.position;
}
```

In a real project you would probably do some conversion from the object model position to the position on screen (e.g. GPS data to pixels) but here this is left out for simplicity.

After having done that we still need to set up our layout. This has the following properties:

```
@interface AULYAutomationObjectLayout : UICollectionViewLayout

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *draggedObject;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint dragPosition;

@end
```

And the following implementation:

```
@implementation AULYAutomationObjectLayout

- (void)setDraggedObject:(NSIndexPath *)draggedObject
{
    _draggedObject = draggedObject;
    [self invalidateLayout];
}

- (void)setDragPosition:(CGPoint)dragPosition
{
    _dragPosition = dragPosition;
    [self invalidateLayout];
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    id viewDelegate = self.collectionView.delegate;
    if ([viewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getPositionForItemAtIndexPath:)])
    {
        CGPoint itemPosition = [viewDelegate getPositionForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        layoutAttributes.center = itemPosition;
        layoutAttributes.size = CGSizeMake(ITEM_SIZE, ITEM_SIZE);
    }

    if ([self.draggedObject isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        layoutAttributes.center = self.dragPosition;
        layoutAttributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1.0);
        layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1;
    }

    return layoutAttributes;
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableArray *allAttributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [allAttributes addObject:layoutAttributes];
    }
    return allAttributes;
}

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}

- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{
    return [self.collectionView frame].size;
}

@end
```

To set the custom layout in the storyboard just go to the properties of the controller view and select custom as the layout type - then select your custom class.

Now to enable drag and drop support with the long press gesture simply add the following to your controller:

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    AULYAutomationObjectLayout *automationLayout = (AULYAutomationObjectLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint initialPinchPoint = [sender locationInView:self.collectionView];
        NSIndexPath* tappedCellPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:initialPinchPoint];
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            automationLayout.draggedObject = tappedCellPath;
            automationLayout.dragPosition = initialPinchPoint;
        } completion:nil];
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        automationLayout.dragPosition = [sender locationInView:self.collectionView];
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        AULYAutomationObject *automationObject = self.objects[automationLayout.draggedObject.item];
        automationObject.position = [sender locationInView:self.collectionView];
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            automationLayout.draggedObject = nil;
            automationLayout.dragPosition = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

**One important note:**(this cost me at least an hour): When using the transform3D you should make sure to import QuartzCore into your linked frameworks (in the project properties below the orientation settings). Otherwise you will get a Mach-O Linker Error saying that _CATransform3DMakeScale can not be found.